# Postgresql Column Not Found, But Shows in Describe

Tags: sql, postgresql, quoted-identifier

There have been similar posts, but none helped me solve my problem.

I am trying to do a simple select on a table, retrieving only one column. The column shows in the describe table, but when I try to select it I get a column not found error. I am using the command line interface.

**Table:**

```
 id                        | integer                  | not null default 
 amazon_payment_id         | integer                  | not null
 source                    | character varying(10)    | not null
 timestamp                 | timestamp with time zone | not null
 status                    | character varying(50)    | not null
 statusReason              | character varying(100)   | not null
 transactionId             | character varying(50)    | not null
 transactionDate           | timestamp with time zone | 
 transactionAmount         | numeric(6,2)             | 
 errorMessage              | character varying(100)   | not null
```

etc.

**Select:**

```
select `transactionAmount` from ... where ... group by transactionAmount;
```

**Error:**

```
ERROR:  column "transactionamount" does not exist
LINE 1: select `transactionAmount` from ... where...
```

Does anyone have any idea why I would receive this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why do you use `` ` `` in column name?

You can use it without any quote characters, while with quote characters it may be case sensitive. Also such quote char is `"`, and not `` ` ``

So use:

```
select "transactionAmount" 
from ... 
where ... 
group by "transactionAmount";
```

Read about identifiers at: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html

Comment: Thank you. I tried the back ticks as a last resort, I didn't think of double quotes. The double quotes fixed it for me.